# Vue Resource - 401 (Unauthorized)

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue.js, vue-resource

[image: browser console screenshot]

when I call the method "getUserData" I unfortunately get a 401 (Unauthorized)" error. But if call the URL "http://ppstemp.com/api/User/Profile" with GET and the same headers in Postman, it works!`
how i set my request headers??

```
this.$http.get('http://ppstemp.com/api/User/Profile',{params:{
        n: ...
      }} , {
          headers: {
            "Authorization": "bearer "+ localStorage.getItem('token') ,
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "cache-control": "no-cache"
          }
        }).then(
             (response) => {
               // Handle data returned
                console.log(response.data);
            },
            //error callback
            (err) => console.log(err));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Vue resource get method signature looks like -

```
this.$http.get('/someUrl', [options]).then(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

You need to pass params along with the headers object.

```
this.$http.get('http://ppstemp.com/api/User/Profile', {
  params: {
    n: ...
  },
  headers: {
    "Authorization": "bearer " + localStorage.getItem('token'),
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache"
  }
}).then(
  (response) => {
    // Handle data returned
    console.log(response.data);
  },
  //error callback
  (err) => console.log(err));
}
```

Comment: i sent params !!
this is my headers error and not set with my token and not changed in request

Comment: I think Tushar's point is that the code example you posted is passing the headers as a third argument to the get() method, like this: `this.$http.get(url, options, headers)`. Maybe that's a typo in your post?